# How to use hover with multi-line in bokeh?

Tags: python-2.7, visualization, bokeh, series

I'm facing issues with multi-line figure in bokeh. i can't get the values when i show my graph. i'm using series data type.

Code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("Data.csv", parse_dates=["time"])
result = df.groupby(['time','up','down'], as_index = False)['up', 'down'].sum()

p = Figure(width=500, height=250,logo =None, 
    sizing_mode='scale_width', 
    tools="pan, box_zoom, wheel_zoom, save, reset, box_select",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    title="Graph:", 
    x_axis_label="Time Frame", 
    y_axis_label="Utilization (GB)",
    toolbar_location="below",
    toolbar_sticky=False)


up = result["up"]
time = result["time"]
down = result["down"]

p.multi_line(xs = [time, time], ys = [up, down], color=['#2828B0', '#BC0096'], line_width=1, legend='graph_1')
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Time', '@time'),
                         ('data', '@up')])
p.add_tools(hover)
p.show()
```

[image: Graph link !!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` fields of hover tooltips refer to columns in Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` objects. Since you have not created a CDS explicitly with column names of your choice, Bokeh makes one for you with the standard column name `xs` and `ys` in this case. So:

```
HoverTool(tooltips = [
    ('Time', '@xs'),
    ('data', '@ys')]
)
```

That will put a hover that displays over all segments in the multi-line. There is no way to have a hover work for just one or the other. If you need that, you will have to use separate calls to `line` instead of `multi_line`.

Comment: many thanx bigreddot for your response and the great clarification here. the hove show up now, but the problem it show me the entire data when i hover over a single point. how could i fix that ??

Comment: Hrm, there might actually be a bug then. I'd encourage you to file a GitHub issue with a complete minimal script to reproduce. In the mean time I can only suggest using `line` instead of `multi_line`

Comment: A *complete* script would still be a huge help, and adding one to that issue would be very appreciated.